# How do I dual-boot Ubuntu 14.04 with 3 drives?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot

At the moment, I currently have 2 drives installed in my machine. A 64gb SSD that contains Windows 7, and a 1TB HDD that contains all other data (such as most programs, downloads, etc). Is it possible for me to use a second drive for Ubuntu, whilst keeping my current setup for Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Start by doing a [vanilla](https://www.wordnik.com/words/vanilla) installation of Ubuntu on the second hard drive (the one you referred to in your question as "a second drive for Ubuntu"). Make sure that you select the right hard drive in the Ubuntu installer, so that you don't accidentally overwrite the data on either the 64GB SSD that contains Windows 7 or the 1TB hard drive that contains all other data!

After that you have to ensure that the computer will boot after installing Ubuntu. To do this enter your computer's BIOS or UEFI, whatever your computer has, and change the boot sequence so that the hard drive on which you have installed Ubuntu is the first device in the boot sequence. In some BIOSs the boot sequence menu is called the Boot Device Priority or the Hard Disk Boot Priority.

When you start the computer, it will look for the GRUB bootloader which was installed by the  Ubuntu installer on this hard drive, and then display the GRUB menu, allowing you to select booting to either Ubuntu or Windows 7 operating system.